# Microsoft SQL Server Not Showing Server Name in object Explorer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssms

I Recently Installed Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SSMS) on my local machine for development learning purposes. I am running Windows 10 32 bit. When i try to connect, Server Name does not appear. Screen Shot is attached.

[image: Server name Not Appearing in Object Explorer]

According to my research, name of the local server should appear in the marked field. 
I think that Installation is successful.

I am unable to find the solution to this problem. I installed SSMS 2015 RC0, Problem was not solved. Then i uninstalled it and Installed SSMS 2014. But the problem is not solved. 
I remember perfectly that about a  year ago. I installed SSMS and there was no such problem. I can't figure out Why the server name is not appearing. When i try to connect by manually entering Local server name(./), the following error occurs
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen if MSSQL service is running in SQL configuration manager  ? Sometimes in windows 10 the service does't start automatically and we must start manually

Comment: @Awais, Have you checked through drop down button with 'browse from more' and 'local Servers'.

Comment: Please Install SQL Server Data Tools from link (SSDT)  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2052454

You can also Install it when you are installing Visual Studio there is Option "Data Storage and Processing" you must be select while installing Visual Studio

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have only installed SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), and not SQL Server.

SSMS is the tool used to connect to and manage SQL Server Instances, if you haven't installed a SQL Server instance you have nothing to run your queries against!

Press Windows Key + R (Run) and type services.msc, check to see if the 'SQL Server' appears and that it is running.

Comment: Please Install SQL Server Data Tools from link (SSDT) go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2052454 You can also Install it when you are installing Visual Studio there is Option "Data Storage and Processing" you must be select while installing Visual Studio